# Program uses terminal name instead of user input

Tags: c, ssh, terminal

This program is meant to take in a host name and username and connect through SSH using finger, and it has worked before, but when I run it it ignores the user name and uses the name that comes up in my shell so I do not get the correct result.

My shell starts with Matt$ and this program ends up running Matt@server instead of userName@server.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
std::string CommandString;

char buffer1 [274];

printf("Enter your Host Name; it must be characters and not more than 255");
char hostName[254];
int len2;
fgets(hostName, sizeof(hostName), stdin);
rewind (stdin);
len2 = strlen(hostName);
if(hostName[len2-1] == '\n') hostName[--len2] = '\0';
if(len2 >254 ||!isalpha(hostName[len2-1]))
{
    printf("Invalid Host Name");


}


printf("Enter your User Name; it must be characters and not more than 20");
char userName[19];
int len;
fgets(userName, sizeof(userName), stdin);
rewind (stdin);
len = strlen(userName);
if(userName[len-1] == '\n') userName[--len] = '\0';
if(len >19 || isalpha(userName[19]))
{

    printf("Invalid User Name");


}


sprintf(buffer1,"ssh %s usr/bin/finger %s",hostName,userName);
system((char*)buffer1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So many things, this is mostly `c` with a few `c++` things so it won't compile with `gcc` thrown in, like the unused `std::string` at the top and the `#includes`. Both calls to `fgets()` run the risk of having a string without a `'\0`' at the end since they read the full size of the buffer and never set `buf[sizeof buf - 1] = '\0'` before doing `strlen()`. Finally, are you trying to call `finger` on the remote machine? You'll need a leading `/` and to structure `<username>@<hostname>` correctly.

Comment: Yes I am trying to call finger on the remote machine. Okay, I will clear it up with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you have usr/bin/finger in between the hostname and the username. Are you ntending to run /usr/sbin/finger on the remote host?

You should change this line

```
sprintf(buffer1,"ssh %s usr/bin/finger %s",hostName,userName);
```

to

```
sprintf(buffer1,"ssh -l %s %s /usr/bin/finger",userName,hostname);
```

Give it a try.